# How do I specify a list of parameters so $route can parse them?

Tags: angularjs

If I wanted a single parameter, I could say

```
 $routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId', {....
```

But I need an arbitrarily long list

```
 $routeProvider.when('/Books/:bookId1/:bookId2/:bookId3', {....
```

isn't practical and just saying

```
 $routeProvider.when('/Book/', {....
```

and pointing to `#/Book/?bookId=12&bookId=34&bookId=56` doesn't actually work.

The only thing that I've found is `#/Book/?bookIds=12,34,56` and that is just too lame for words.

Answer (score 0):

The [comment](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider#comment-668354974) on the AngularJS docs page indicates that you will probably have to use $location.path() and parse variable arguments yourself.

> The only thing that I've found is #/Book/?bookIds=12,34,56 and that is
>   just too lame for words.

It's not actually very lame if you reconsider the resource you're *querying*.
If you realize that you're actually asking your web service for a collection of books, then you may end up with something like `/Books/?q=...` or `/BookList/?q=...`